# rsyncd ignoring secrets file

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I've got rsyncd running, but it seems to be ignoring the secrets file: I can connect on port 873 (so not over ssh) with incorrect usernames and passwords from two different systems using two different clients.

/etc/rsyncd.conf contains:

```
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid

charset = utf-8

[kara_homes]
  path = /home/kara/homes
  uid = kara
  gid = kara
  read only = false
  auth users = qnap
  secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.passwd
```

The /etc/rsyncd.passwd contains one qnap:password line. I currently can connect with user "abc". Running on Ubuntu 20.

I've moved configuration around (like the auth users and secrets file to the top), but that does not make a difference.

Looking in the log file, `grep rsyncd /var/log/syslog` gives me

```
nyota rsyncd[445149]: connect from 82-xxx-xxx-56.fixed.kpn.net (82.xxx.xxx.56)
nyota rsyncd[445149]: module-list request from 82-xxx-xxx-56.fixed.kpn.net (82.xxx.xxx.56)
```

How come?

Comment: Yes I have restarted rsyncd (even just now again). The clients I've used (acrosync and qnap) are executing the rsync commands, I do not type them from the command line. But that should not matter, because the rsyncd should dictate that I requires a login? The unwanted user accounts were never part of the secrets file; I can type any username I want.

Comment: How do you know the connections aren't using `ssh`/`rsync` instead of `rsyncd`?

Comment: Because they list the data sources defined in the /etc/rsyncd.config, ssh would list the user's home directory folders. And because I checked-off the SSH checkbox in the client, the client says it is using port 873 instead of 22. And I see an access entry in the syslog for rsyncd. And because that if I enable ssh, I actually do need to login using an existing system user. :-) This only happens with ssh off over port 873.

Comment: QNAP is outbound; I want to sync QNAP to an Ubuntu server as an off-site backup. The actual problem is compound; rsync-over-ssh does not show the /home directory on my Ubuntu, so QNAP support suggested using rsyncd while they are looking into it, but that has this security problem. With FTP QNAP complains about unsupported commands by the FTP server.

Comment: Nope there are just two lines in the syslog nyota rsyncd[445149]: connect from 82-xxx-xxx-56.fixed.kpn.net (82.xxx.xxx.56)
nyota rsyncd[445149]: module-list request from 82-xxx-xxx-56.fixed.kpn.net (82.xxx.xxx.56)